# Can't UPDATE a database table

Tags: mysql, innodb, update

I'm getting a 'Error synchronizing data with database' error on MySQL 5.6.10 (on AWS).
Trying to update a field (using dBeaver) but getting error message/

Further: Data truncated for column source_account_number at row 1. ?

I HAVE expanded out the size of this column from 15 to 30 characters (VARCHAR)and there were no reported problems. Engine is InnoDB.

Stumped as to what to try next.

DDL for table

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `record_type` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_account_number` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_account_description` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_branch_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `department_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_of_account` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `spi` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fccs_account` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fccs_account_description` text,
  `icp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kpmg_account` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_account` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`record_type`,`source_account_number`,`company_code`),
  KEY `key_mapping_table_FK` (`kpmg_account`),
  KEY `key_mapping_table_FK_1` (`department_id`),
  KEY `key_mapping_table_FK_2` (`company_branch_id`),
  KEY `key_mapping_table_FK_3` (`account_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cons_mapping_table_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`kpmg_account`) REFERENCES `kpmg`.`kpmg_account_list` (`KPMG_account`),
  CONSTRAINT `cons_mapping_table_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cons_mapping_table_FK_2` FOREIGN KEY (`company_branch_id`) REFERENCES `dealer_info` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `cons_mapping_table_FK_3` FOREIGN KEY (`account_category_id`) REFERENCES `account_category` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=53005 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What is the query you're using to update it?

Comment: `UPDATE reporting.mapping_table set company_branch_id = 1 where id = 52884;`

Comment: Can you please add the DDL of your `mapping_table` to your post (in addition to the query you mentioned above)? Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of source_account_number at row 1?

Comment: Let's see the `ALTER`.